# Access Table Update from Form

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a form linked to a table.  I am trying to use the me.dirty function to see if the user changed anything.  For now I put the code msgbox(me.dirty) in the form close button to determine what is happening.  When some fields are changed i get true others i get false.  For now I am only changing one field at a time.  I have determined that if I look at the table before I close the form, if the table matches the form me.dirty is false.  if not then me.dirty is true.  this makes sense I dirty=true when the form does not match the table.

What I cannot figure out is why some field match the table and others do not until the form is closed.  For example I have two check boxes one is always matching the table as soon as i check or uncheck it and dirty = false.  The other one does not change the table until I close the form and dirty=true.  Iv'e looked at all the properties of the two check boxes and they are the same.

I also have two drop downs that give me dirty=true and two text boxes that always give me dirty = false.  (both cases when the field is changed.)

Any help would be appreciated as I am stumped right now.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out on my own.  The ones where me.dirty=false had an event after update that put focus on a subform, this updated the table and then when clicked the button to run me.dirty, it was false.